# Procedure or function has too many arguments SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I getting this error while executing the stored procedure in SQL Server:

> Msg 8144, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_adduser, Line 2
>   Procedure or function sp_adduser has too many arguments specified.

The weird thing is that the number of parameters is the same as declared in the procedure, even when I execute it while right-click on the procedure and press execute, input the parameters from the fields and still the same error.

This is the code of the procedure and the exec:

```
create procedure [dbo].[sp_addUser]
(
    @userID nvarchar(50),
    @pw nvarchar(50),
    @fName nvarchar(50),
    @lname nvarchar(50),
    @email nvarchar(150),
    @address nvarchar(150),
    @city int, 
    @country int,
    @phone nvarchar(50),
    @gender nvarchar(10),
    @dob date,
    @photo nvarchar(150),
    @secq int, 
    @secAnswer  nvarchar(150),
    @completed int output)
as

declare @found int

/*
usertype:
0 - Administrator
1 - User
*/

begin
    begin
        select @found=count(*) from registration r
        where REPLACE(r.firstname,' ','')=REPLACE(@fName,' ','')
        and REPLACE(r.lastname,' ','')=REPLACE(@lname,' ','')
        and r.dateofbirth=@dob;
    end
    begin
        if @found=0
        begin
            begin
                insert into Login values(@userID,@pw,0,1);
            end
            begin
                insert into registration values(
                @userID,@fName,@lname,@email,
                @address,@city,@country,@phone,
                @gender,@dob,@photo,@secq,@secAnswer
                )
            end
            begin
            set @completed=1;
            end
        end
        else set @completed=0
    end
    return @completed
end
```

And here is the exec:

```
DECLARE @return_value int,
        @completed int

SELECT  @completed = 0

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_addUser]
        @userID = N'a',
        @pw = N'a',
        @fName = N'a',
        @lname = N'a',
        @email = N'a',
        @address = N'a',
        @city = 1,
        @country = 1,
        @phone = N'a',
        @gender = N'a',
        @dob = '01/01/2000',
        @photo = N'a',
        @secq = 1,
        @secAnswer = N'a',
        @completed = @completed OUTPUT

SELECT  @completed as N'@completed'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Also: naming your stored procedure in such a *generic* way as `sp_adduser` has caused you to collide with a pre-existing system stored procedure. Try to **(a)** not use any prefix - and **most definitely** not `sp_`, and **(b)** try to use **more meaningful**, more expressive names, like `AddMySystemUser` or something like that - something that's highly unlikely to collide with a pre-existing name

Comment: @marc_s: nice link on the performance issue -- I'd always wondered if the cache miss issue was really significant. Turns out, yes, it is.

Comment: thanks @marc_s. I will keep it in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sp_adduser is a procedure which is built-in to SQL Server - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181422.aspx

[Don't use the sp_ prefix for your own stored procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd172115), maybe call it proc_adduser instead, I think that will work

Comment: Yes, it was the problem. I will select @Elliveny as answer since it was first. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually calling the system stored procedure [sp_adduser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181422). The "sp_" prefix is special and [has its own rules on resolution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd172115), so using it is recommended against. If you want to use your own prefix, whatever you do, don't use "sp_".

Per @marc_s, even if your stored procedure doesn't clash with an existing system stored procedure, you will still get a [noticeable performance hit](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix) due to cache misses.